# Finding paired values for same variable in R

Tags: r

I am a very bigger biologist trying to learn R. and I have a data set as follows:

```
set group 
A    10
B    10 
A    11
A    11
A    34
B    34
B    67
```

I am trying to pull out all pairs where the groups are identical but sets are different. For example, my ideal output should look like as follows:

```
set group 
A    10
B    10 
A    34
B    34
```

I have tried the following code but I did not get what I am looking for. Could someone please help with this?  Thanks in advance.

```
for (i in group) {
    if(set == "A" || (set == "B")) {
      print(set)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an option with `dplyr` where we group by 'group' and then `filter` to keep the number of distinct elements of 'set' is 2

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
  group_by(group) %>% 
  filter(n_distinct(set) == 2)
# A tibble: 4 x 2
#  set   group
#  <chr> <int>
#1 A        10
#2 B        10
#3 A        34
#4 B        34
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(set = c("A", "B", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B"),
  group = c(10L, 
  10L, 11L, 11L, 34L, 34L, 67L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
 -7L))
```

Answer (score 1):

We can rely on R base

```
> do.call(rbind, lapply(split(dat, dat$group), function(x) x[length(unique(x$set))==2]))
     set group
10.1   A    10
10.2   B    10
34.5   A    34
34.6   B    34
```

Answer (score 1):

Also a `dplyr` possibility:

```
df %>%
 group_by(group) %>%
 filter(n() == 2 & any(set != first(set)))

  set   group
  <chr> <int>
1 A        10
2 B        10
3 A        34
4 B        34
```